# Can only Framework Elements subscribe to property change notifications?

Tags: silverlight

I have been looking at both INotifyPropertyChanged and creating custom Dependency Properties.  What I wanted to be able to do is have, for example, the colors of fixed ink strokes on an ink presenter or variables in code subscribe to a color property in a class that's been fitted out appropriately and then update themselves whenever the color property of the class changes.  I'm beginning to think that it is not possible to do this - thoughts or solutions please anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can, normally you'd use bindings for that (there's a good few ways to bind up objects). In your scenario binding source is you color settings and the binding target is you presenter's FrameworkElement. Could you concretise what types of objects do you have on both sides, as in POCO source - FrameworkElement target or something else.